# Can an outfielder leave the ballpark?

Tags: rules, baseball

I was watching a baseball game and saw the outfielder partially climb the wall in the outfield to try and rob a homerun. This made me wonder: can an outfielder climb over the outfield fence and stand in the bleachers? Or does he need to be in fair territory when a pitch is thrown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, yes the fielder must start the play in fair territory.

> 5.02 Fielding Positions
>
> When the ball is put in play at the start of, or during a game, all fielders other than the catcher shall be on fair
> territory.

You mentioned partially climbing a wall.  Climbing *upon* a wall (but not beyond) is specifically allowed.  From a comment to 5.09(a)(1):

> A fielder may reach over a fence, railing, rope or other line of
> demarcation to make a catch. He may jump on top of a railing, or
> canvas that may be in foul ground.

But that doesn't give permission to leave the field entirely and go into the stands.  The MLB Umpire Manual is a bit more explicit here (my bolding):

> **The fielder is confined to the limits of the playing field**, but may
> reach over any fence, railing, or any line of demarcation to make a
> catch. The fielder may also jump on top of a railing marking the
> boundary of the field or on any tarp that may be on foul ground in
> order to make a play. (See also Section 8.1 [Legal Catch].)

> 8.1 LEGAL CATCH
>
> ...
>
> **A fielder may not jump over any fence, railing, or rope marking the limits of the playing field in order to catch the ball.** A fielder may (1) reach over such fence, railing, or rope to make a catch;

So a fielder can climb the fence.  And in the process of making a catch can fall over the fence.  But the fielder is not allowed beyond the fence before making the catch.  Standing in the bleachers to make a play on a batted ball is not allowed.  A fielder doing so would not be awarded a legal catch.